# How do I teach WebStorm 9 inspector to recognize Angular Material Design tags/attributes?

Tags: webstorm

Currently, all my angular material HTML attributes are highlighted in yellow with WebStorm 9 (Mac OS X Yosemite) warning: "Attribute [name] is not allowed here".

[image]

How can I teach WS to automatically recognize these attributes as valid? I am aware that I can add each one one-by-one to the list of custom attributes, but was hoping that there would be a better way to do this.

**UPDATE:**
Just wanted to clarify that this issue applies to [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/#/) project, and not the AngularJS itself.

Comment: It would be realy great to get support for this

Answer (score 18):

You need to add the `angular-material.js` file as a Library in WebStorm:

1. **Open Preferences** (Mac: `Cmd+,`, Win/Linux: `Ctrl+Alt+S`)
2. **Go to `Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries`**

   [image: Preferences > Libraries]
3. **Click `Add` and then press the `+` icon**

   [image]
4. **Find `angular-material.js` in your `node_modules` folder**

   [image]
5. **Add a Name and a version and press `Ok`**

Now you will have completions for all elements and attributes that have an `@ngdoc` documentation in the `angular-material` source code.

#### Usage

- Start typing and you will see the completions:

[image]

- Pressing `F1` (Ctrl+Q on Win/Linux) will also show some docs, if available in the source code:
  [image]

#### Important note

Not all features are properly documented, the following won't show up (unless you already used them) cause they are defined dynamically in a loop, with no `@ngdoc` for them:

```
var API_WITH_VALUES = [ "layout", "flex", "flex-order", "flex-offset", "layout-align" ];
var API_NO_VALUES   = [ "show", "hide", "layout-padding", "layout-margin" ];
```

So for these you'd have to add them as a custom attribute (`Alt+Enter` > "Add flex to custom html attributes").

#### Environment

Tested on a Mac OS X 10.11.4 using WebStorm 2016.1.1, but this should work for older versions as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a solution only for typescript bindings and not for the HTML markup elements and attributes.

Comment: @MichaelTrouw Not sure what you mean, I don't use TypeScript, and I get auto-complete for Angular Material attributes (those that are exposed).

Comment: (I cannot @ your username, bytheway, annoying..) copy random bits of angular-material example HTML and check if you see any orange-underlined attributes (there should be). maybe those are exposed, maybe they are not, in any case they are used by angular-material and I don't want them to show up as warnings.

case in point: in my Webstorm editor, the first piece of example HTML at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction 
shows a warning for the ```show``` directive. it shouldn't.

**EDIT:** I see now that ```show``` is included under important notes. but there are more!

Comment: @MichaelTrouw Yes, you are correct, most of them are marked, and as I mentioned under Important note (this includes variations like `flex-md`).
There's really nothing we can do with that except ask the Angular Material guys to add \@ngDoc for those stuff, but they're too busy with Material 2 that they don't have time for anything.
Just add them as a custom attributes (Alt+Enter on the attribute).

Comment: Nice. This does it for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Angular 11.

Answer (score 14):

I am using `PHPStorm`, which is a sister Project of `WebStorm`, but it should work the same way.

You maybe need to add the Library:

[image]

- File
- Settings
- Languages & Frameworks
- Javascript
- Librarys

Add here AngularJS

If this does not work, you can add them manually:

[image]

Follow this Steps:

- File
- Default Settings
- Editor
- Inspection
- HTML
- Unknown HTML tag attributes

To the right you will see in Options "Custom HTML tag attributes". Enter here the attributes you want to allow.

Comment: Thank you. Adding each of Angular Material HTML attributes as a separate tag and maintaining them over time would not be feasible. There's gotta be a better way of doing it. Maybe in the future.

Answer (score 5):

I highly recomend you to install the [Angular.js plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971?pr=idea):

1. Go to menu File > Settings (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> if you're on Windows);
2. Select Plugins in the window that'll open;
3. Click in the Browse Repositories button;
4. Type AngularJS in the search field. Select the plugin;
5. Click Install Plugin.

The plugin is incumbed to read `@ngdoc` annotations present in ngMaterial sources and create documentation for their directives.

[It seems to support WebStorm and other IDEs](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/tree/master/AngularJS), but I could not find it in the plugin registry while filtering by other IDEs. Maybe it'll work inside WebStorm...

Anyway, this is what you get:

[image]

Comment: I do already have AngularJS plugin enabled. I am having issues with WebStorm 9 (on latest Mac OS X) not recognizing Angular Material html attributes and not the AngularJS itself. Angular Material is a separate project from AngularJS.

Comment: @demisx I'm well aware of the differences between these projects. You need that plugin AND the ngMaterial sources. The plugin reads the `@ngdoc` annotations and document the directives in your HTML. An example is available in the screenshot I provided.

Comment: I see. I have AngularJS plug-in enabled (Version 139.1112) and the ngMaterial sources are in the `bower_components` folder. The latter is marked as "library home". Looks like attributes defined as directives in ngMaterial JS file are recognized, but attributes defined in ngMaterial CSS not e.g. `layout-fill`, `hide-sm` etc. I guess this is because CSS doesn't have docs. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This specifically helped me with the Unknown tag issue (I'd disabled the plugin in the hope of reducing cpu/memory usage), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have also a plugin that helps a lot, check it out. It helps a lot

[Angular material v2, Teradata covalent v1, Angular flex layout v1 & Material icon live templates](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9490-angular-material-design-v2-teradata-covalent-v1-angular-flex-layout-v1--material-icon-snippets) 
And with the solution provided by @Alex Ilyaev gives a lot of help.

[image: Plugin]

[image: Helps]

But its no perfect.

[image: Not every tag]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I don't think that idea's AngularJS plugin understands angular-materials attribute extensions.

It does understand the directives i.e. control click **<md-button** ...> and the directive (custom tag) is found.

For now you will have to add the attributes af custom attributes in order to get a "green" page.