# How to integrate WebStorm with Vue.js

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, vue.js, jetbrains-ide

WebStorm didn't support [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) natively (at least for now - Apr, 2016).

I've find few advice how to improve WebStorm experience.
Now I want to list them in one place (I'll answer my own question below).

**Feel free to improve the answer**

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**WebStorm now supports vue.js** (starting from **2017.1** [[blog]](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/02/webstorm-2017-1-eap-171-2822/))

So no additional steps required

---

**DEPRECATED**

This is the checklist of ways to improve WebStorm(PhpStorm, Idea, etc.) experience:

1. **Use Vue.js plugin**.

**UPDATE**: Both plugins have own problems atm

- [vue-for-idea](https://github.com/henjue/vue-for-idea) has weird [side-effects](https://github.com/henjue/vue-for-idea/issues/46) (hiding `node_modules` from project view);
- [John Kelly's Vue.js plugin](https://github.com/postalservice14/vuejs-plugin) force you to use special declarations for ES6 and scss, sass (see deprecated section below)

> You can install it via `Settings(Preferences)` => `Plugins` => `Browse repositories` => (search for) "vue"

choose one or both: "Vue.js" or "vue-for-idea". It's up to you.

2. **Set "Javascript Language Version" to ES6**.

> Open `Settings(Preferences)` => `Language & Frameworks` =>
>   `JavaScript`. Set `Javascript Language Version` to `ECMAcript6`
>
> https://github.com/postalservice14/vuejs-plugin

3. **Improve HTML-tag's attributes highlighting**

> Open `Settings(Preferences)` => `Editor` => `Inspection` => `HTML` => 
>   select `Unknown HTML tag attributes` => click `Custom HTML tag attributes`.
>   Add your attributes.

For example, my list:

> v-on,v-on:click,v-on:change,v-on:focus,v-on:blur,v-on:keyup,:click,@click,v-model,v-text,v-bind,:disabled,@submit,v-class,:class,v-if,:value,v-for,scoped,@click.prevent,number,:readonly,@input,@click,v-show,v-else,readonly,v-link,:title,:for,tab-index,:name,:id,:checked,transition,@submit.prevent,autocapitalize,autocorrect,slot,v-html,:style

P.S. For the full list of custom tags check [@Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40097776/930170) answer below

P.P.S. Actually it's should work in more common way:

> Open `Settings(Preferences)` => `Languages & Frameworks` => `Javascript` => 
>   `Libraries` => click `Add`
>   (after this you should set path to the `vue.js`. You can dowmload it with npm or whatever)

(More info in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28903910/930170)

But I didn't get success with that.

4. **Enable Node.js Coding Assistance:**

Open `Settings(Preferences)` => `Languages & Frameworks` => `Node.js and NPM`

> If "Node.js core library is not enabled", click button `Enabled`

---

**DEPRECATED** (may be required if you don't use vue plugins for IDE):

1. **Make `*.vue` files to be recognized as a html flies**.

> Open `Settings(Preferences)` => `Editor` =>`File Types` find `HTML` in
>   `Recognized File Types`, then add `*.vue` as a new Registered
>   Patterns.

2. **Improve ES6 highlight**.

> In each `vue` file with  tag:
>
> ```
>     <script type="text/babel">
>         // your code here...
>     </script>
> ```

(This is would help to recognise constructions like `setTimeout(() => {console.log(1) }, 100)`)

3. **Improve styles highlight**. (sass, scss, etc)

> In each `vue` file with  tag:
>
> ```
>     <style lang="sass" rel="stylesheet/sass">
>         // your style here...
>     </style>
> ```

For `scss` it's gonna be `<style lang="scss" type="text/scss">`

For `stylus` please try `<style lang="stylus" type="text/stylus">`

---

**UPD**: The steps below are not so trusted, they *may* helps, or may not, some of them I didn't check personally, or I didn't catch is any effect exist or not.

1. **Import TextMate Bundle functionality**.

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/textmate-bundles.html?origin=old_help

2. **Import TypeScript tables for vue**.

> Open `Settings(Preferences)` => `Language & Frameworks` =>
>   `JavaScript` => `Libraries`. Click `Download`, Switch to `TypeScript community stubs`. And download all tabs with `vue` word.
>
> Example: https://youtu.be/4mKiGkokyx8?t=84 (from 1:24)

---

**UPD2:** For **more info** check the issue at github: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-syntax-highlight/issues/3

---

**UPD3:** FAQ:

1. **Can I improve `pug`(`jade`) highlight**?

   - **No**. Because Webstorm doesn't support template language injection... [Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FIDEA-106449#tab=Comments) has been up since 2013 with no official word.

Comment: The trick `<style lang="sass" rel="stylesheet/sass">` doesn't work for me. Even setting `lang="scss"` doesn't help, it tries to read pure css so it's full of errors. Also, it messes auto indentation. Are you sure about this or am I missing something? EDIT: just found that it should work https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14762

Comment: oh, figured it out. `<style lang="scss" type="text/scss" scoped></style>` is what worked for me.

Comment: For improve HTML-tag's attributes highlighting be aware about XML inspection which can cause problems with html inspection.

Comment: Thanks for this exhaustive analysis, which was a great help. However neither of the plug-ins are any good in WebStorm for the reasons you stated. Nor did the list of extra HTML tag attributes make any difference, for some reason. What **does** work is assigning .vue files to HTML, and then using vue shorthand - i.e. @ instead of v-on, and just ':' instead of v-bind. However I would much prefer v-on to @, because it says what it's doing.

Comment: Anyone here have a clue on how to modify the default tab indentation spacing for the template area? Using the vue.js plugin, everything is good but i'm not able to change the tab spacing from 4 to 2. Same thing is also true for styles. Only the script area reads in the tab spacing settings.

Comment: Is there any way to use the official plugin in IntelliJ IDEA? I can clone the plugin from the official git repository alright but I couldn't find a way to build and install it... Also it doesn't seem to be available yet in the list of official plugins if I try to directly install from `Settings`. I would rather just stick to IntelliJ IDEA for all my developments instead of having to explicitly launch WebStorm for this purpose.

Comment: @JIXiang have no ideas about plugin. But you can do all the way work around and make it work without plugin (see deprecated section above)

Comment: I am still not able to use vue in webstorm, even though I am using Wbstorm 2017. Any ideas?

Comment: @YasserHussain That's weird. Are you sure, that you're using a correct version, cause it's in Early Access Preview right now. Otherwise you can try to follow up this answer

Comment: @SergeyPanfilov *.vue was under JSX file type for some reason. Fixed it. No worries.

Answer (score 17):

I updated the list of unknown HTML tags so you just have to copy-paste this in the PhpStorm setting :

```
nobr, noembed, comment, noscript, embed, script, :checked, :class, :click, :disabled, :for, :id, :name, :readonly, :style, :title, :value, @click, @click.prevent, @click.stop, @click.capture, @click.self, @drag, @drag.prevent, @drag.stop, @drag.capture, @drag.self, @dragend, @dragend.prevent, @dragend.stop, @dragend.capture, @dragend.self, @dragenter, @dragenter.prevent, @dragenter.stop, @dragenter.capture, @dragenter.self, @dragleave, @dragleave.prevent, @dragleave.stop, @dragleave.capture, @dragleave.self, @dragover, @dragover.prevent, @dragover.stop, @dragover.capture, @dragover.self, @dragstart, @dragstart.prevent, @dragstart.stop, @dragstart.capture, @dragstart.self, @drop, @drop.prevent, @drop.stop, @drop.capture, @drop.self, @input, @input.prevent, @input.stop, @input.capture, @input.self, @submit, @submit.prevent, @submit.stop, @submit.capture, @submit.self, scoped, slot, tab-index, v-bind, v-class, v-else, v-for, v-html, v-if, v-link, v-model, v-on, v-on:input, v-on:input.prevent, v-on:input.stop, v-on:input.capture, v-on:input.self, v-on:submit, v-on:submit.prevent, v-on:submit.stop, v-on:submit.capture, v-on:submit.self, v-on:blur, v-on:blur.prevent, v-on:blur.stop, v-on:blur.capture, v-on:blur.self, v-on:change, v-on:change.prevent, v-on:change.stop, v-on:change.capture, v-on:change.self, v-on:click, v-on:click.prevent, v-on:click.stop, v-on:click.capture, v-on:click.self, v-on:focus, v-on:focus.prevent, v-on:focus.stop, v-on:focus.capture, v-on:focus.self, v-on:keypress, v-on:keypress.prevent, v-on:keypress.stop, v-on:keypress.capture, v-on:keypress.self, v-on:keyup, v-on:keyup.prevent, v-on:keyup.stop, v-on:keyup.capture, v-on:keyup.self, v-on:keyup.enter, v-on:keyup.enter.prevent, v-on:keyup.enter.stop, v-on:keyup.enter.capture, v-on:keyup.enter.self, v-on:keyup.tab, v-on:keyup.tab.prevent, v-on:keyup.tab.stop, v-on:keyup.tab.capture, v-on:keyup.tab.self, v-on:keyup.delete, v-on:keyup.delete.prevent, v-on:keyup.delete.stop, v-on:keyup.delete.capture, v-on:keyup.delete.self, v-on:keyup.esc, v-on:keyup.esc.prevent, v-on:keyup.esc.stop, v-on:keyup.esc.capture, v-on:keyup.esc.self, v-on:keyup.space, v-on:keyup.space.prevent, v-on:keyup.space.stop, v-on:keyup.space.capture, v-on:keyup.space.self, v-on:keyup.up, v-on:keyup.up.prevent, v-on:keyup.up.stop, v-on:keyup.up.capture, v-on:keyup.up.self, v-on:keyup.down, v-on:keyup.down.prevent, v-on:keyup.down.stop, v-on:keyup.down.capture, v-on:keyup.down.self, v-on:keyup.left, v-on:keyup.left.prevent, v-on:keyup.left.stop, v-on:keyup.left.capture, v-on:keyup.left.self, v-on:keyup.right, v-on:keyup.right.prevent, v-on:keyup.right.stop, v-on:keyup.right.capture, v-on:keyup.right.self, v-show, v-text, v-on:drag, v-on:drag.prevent, v-on:drag.stop, v-on:drag.capture, v-on:drag.self, v-on:dragend, v-on:dragend.prevent, v-on:dragend.stop, v-on:dragend.capture, v-on:dragend.self, v-on:dragenter, v-on:dragenter.prevent, v-on:dragenter.stop, v-on:dragenter.capture, v-on:dragenter.self, v-on:dragleave, v-on:dragleave.prevent, v-on:dragleave.stop, v-on:dragleave.capture, v-on:dragleave.self, v-on:dragover, v-on:dragover.prevent, v-on:dragover.stop, v-on:dragover.capture, v-on:dragover.self, v-on:dragstart, v-on:dragstart.prevent, v-on:dragstart.stop, v-on:dragstart.capture, v-on:dragstart.self, v-on:drop, v-on:drop.prevent, v-on:drop.stop, v-on:drop.capture, v-on:drop.self, @focus, @focus.prevent, @focus.stop, @focus.capture, @focus.self, @change, @change.prevent, @change.stop, @change.capture, @change.self, @blur, @blur.prevent, @blur.stop, @blur.capture, @blur.self, @keypress, @keypress.prevent, @keypress.stop, @keypress.capture, @keypress.self, @keyup, @keyup.prevent, @keyup.stop, @keyup.capture, @keyup.self, v-on:reset, v-on:reset.prevent, v-on:reset.stop, v-on:reset.capture, v-on:reset.self, @reset, @reset.prevent, @reset.stop, @reset.capture, @reset.self, v-on:keydown, v-on:keydown.prevent, v-on:keydown.stop, v-on:keydown.capture, v-on:keydown.self, @keydown, @keydown.prevent, @keydown.stop, @keydown.capture, @keydown.self, v-on:mousenter, v-on:mousenter.prevent, v-on:mousenter.stop, v-on:mousenter.capture, v-on:mousenter.self, v-on:mouseover, v-on:mouseover.prevent, v-on:mouseover.stop, v-on:mouseover.capture, v-on:mouseover.self, v-on:mousemove, v-on:mousemove.prevent, v-on:mousemove.stop, v-on:mousemove.capture, v-on:mousemove.self, v-on:mousedown, v-on:mousedown.prevent, v-on:mousedown.stop, v-on:mousedown.capture, v-on:mousedown.self, v-on:mouseup, v-on:mouseup.prevent, v-on:mouseup.stop, v-on:mouseup.capture, v-on:mouseup.self, @mousenter, @mousenter.prevent, @mousenter.stop, @mousenter.capture, @mousenter.self, @mouseover, @mouseover.prevent, @mouseover.stop, @mouseover.capture, @mouseover.self, @mousemove, @mousemove.prevent, @mousemove.stop, @mousemove.capture, @mousemove.self, @mousedown, @mousedown.prevent, @mousedown.stop, @mousedown.capture, @mousedown.self, @mouseup, @mouseup.prevent, @mouseup.stop, @mouseup.capture, @mouseup.self, v-on:dblclick, v-on:dblclick.prevent, v-on:dblclick.stop, v-on:dblclick.capture, v-on:dblclick.self, v-on:contextmenu, v-on:contextmenu.prevent, v-on:contextmenu.stop, v-on:contextmenu.capture, v-on:contextmenu.self, v-on:wheel, v-on:wheel.prevent, v-on:wheel.stop, v-on:wheel.capture, v-on:wheel.self, v-on:mouseleave, v-on:mouseleave.prevent, v-on:mouseleave.stop, v-on:mouseleave.capture, v-on:mouseleave.self, v-on:mouseout, v-on:mouseout.prevent, v-on:mouseout.stop, v-on:mouseout.capture, v-on:mouseout.self, v-on:select, v-on:select.prevent, v-on:select.stop, v-on:select.capture, v-on:select.self, @dblclick, @dblclick.prevent, @dblclick.stop, @dblclick.capture, @dblclick.self, @contextmenu, @contextmenu.prevent, @contextmenu.stop, @contextmenu.capture, @contextmenu.self, @wheel, @wheel.prevent, @wheel.stop, @wheel.capture, @wheel.self, @mouseleave, @mouseleave.prevent, @mouseleave.stop, @mouseleave.capture, @mouseleave.self, @mouseout, @mouseout.prevent, @mouseout.stop, @mouseout.capture, @mouseout.self, @select, @select.prevent, @select.stop, @select.capture, @select.self, v-bind:key
```

I would have commented your previous answer, but the character limit prevented me to do so.

Note : there are many more [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) available, and I only hand picked the most common ones, in my own opinion.

Comment: Thanks, mate, I've add a link to your answer in accepted one

Comment: Note : I just updated that list since it missed some comma after the events finishing by '.self'.

Answer (score 3):

I circumvent template-injection with separate template-files which is not very nice ...

```
<template lang="pug" src="./MyComponent.pug">
```

Answer (score 3):

WebStorm started supporting VueJS officially [See their blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/02/webstorm-2017-1-eap-171-2822/)

But now It's only working in **Early Access Preview Build**