# IntelliJ Support for Angular Material 2

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, angular-material

I'm using @angular/material 2.0.0-beta.1, and in IntelliJ I'm getting tons of warnings about unknown attributes, and attributes in the wrong places, etc. I was wondering how to fix this, other than by adding it to custom html attributes (there are far too many to do this sustainably).

Note that angular-material and @angular/material are different in that @angular/material is version 2.0 (still in beta), and its npm package structure is different than that of angular material 1.

[image: Warning image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I teach WebStorm 9 inspector to recognize Angular Material Design tags/attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701863/how-do-i-teach-webstorm-9-inspector-to-recognize-angular-material-design-tags-at)

Comment: No, I'm using angular material 2.0 and the linked question is angular material < 2.0. The npm package structure is different and it uses typescript.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you found a solution?

Comment: I have same problem too, have you found any solution?